How to mount a .iso file via network
I have a small home network and only 1 of my PCs has a CD drive. I created an .iso file of some software I want to install on some of my other PCs. Now it would be no big deal to just move the ISO file to my other computers via network or USB and then mount it. But out of curiosity I tried just mounting it over my network instead, but wasn't successful in doing so. So I wonder: is that even possible?
To make my situation more clear:

I have one ssh server with a ISO file on it.

On one of my PCs I just mounted the folder of the ISO file via sshfs like this:
sshfs ssh-server@IP:/isofolder /mointpoint/for/isofolder


After the (server) drive with the .iso file has been mounted on my client I ran:
sudo mount -o loop /mountpoint/for/isofolder/isofile.iso /mountpoint/for/iso

And this gives me the error couldn't create loop device
Is there another way? Is it even possible to do on a drive that has been mounted with sshfs?

It's possible, but only as long as root is allowed to access the file. All FUSE-based filesystems including sshfs need to be mounted with the -o allow_root (or allow_other) option to allow access from other UIDs as normally FUSE blanket disallows it (to protect root from potentially malicious custom filesystems).

Ty though wouldn't that mean that fuseiso should work since it doesn't seem to need root? Though that fails as well.
